# how to convert sql rows into columns with conditions

Tags: sql, pivot

i have a table where month wise details are stored in one column but i wants to show the months in one column as separate columns. below is my table,

```
---------------------------------------------------
MatrixName                          Month   ActualPerformanceValue
---------------------------------------------------
Matrix 1                          - Jan     98%
Matrix 1                          - Feb     98%
Matrix 2                          - Mar     100%
Matrix 2                          - Apr     90%
```

and i want to output as

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
MatrixName                          Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr
----------------------------------------------------------------
Matrix 1                          -  98%    98%
Matrix 2                          -                 100%    90%
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot+sql)

Comment: What database is it? SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL? Did you search SO for existing questions? What sql have you tried so far?

Comment: its SQL server shah kalpesh

Answer (score 0):

After building a test table and inserting the sample data exposed above, I have worked on a SQL server statement that pivots the data similar to your desired output.

The piece of code is attached below, you'll have only to change the source table. Also, I have taken into account all the months of the year even though the sample data has only a few of them, but you can model the query based on your needs:

```
SELECT
    MatrixName
    , Jan = ISNULL(pvt.Jan, '')
    , Feb = ISNULL(pvt.Feb, '')
    , Mar = ISNULL(pvt.Mar, '')
    , Apr = ISNULL(pvt.Apr, '')
    , May = ISNULL(pvt.May, '')
    , Jun = ISNULL(pvt.Jun, '')
    , Jul = ISNULL(pvt.Jul, '')
    , Aug = ISNULL(pvt.Aug, '')
    , Sep = ISNULL(pvt.Sep, '')
    , Oct = ISNULL(pvt.Oct, '')
    , Nov = ISNULL(pvt.Nov, '')
    , [Dec] = ISNULL(pvt.[Dec], '')
FROM
    (
        SELECT  
            [MatrixName]
            , [Month]
            , [ActualPerformanceValue]
        FROM
            [Test].[dbo].[Matrix]
    ) dt
PIVOT
    (
    MAX([ActualPerformanceValue]) FOR [Month] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul]
                                                    , [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])
    ) pvt
```

Comment: it worked and exactly what I was looking for. thank you so much for the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select matrixname,
       max(case when month = 'Jan' then ActualPerformanceValue end) as jan,
       max(case when month = 'Feb' then ActualPerformanceValue end) as feb,
       . . .   -- continue for the rest of the months that you want.
from t
group by maxtrixname;
```